# What is the difference between _m_empty and _mm_empty?

Tags: c, x86, simd, intrinsics, mmx

While I was looking for MMX functions, I noticed that two of them, `_m_empty` and `_mm_empty`, have [exactly the same definition](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_empty).

So why do they both exist ? Is one of them older than the other ? Is there a difference that is not mentioned in the manual ?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should avoid using MMX. It's deprecated for x64 native development along with AMD 3DNow! and x87. SSE/SSE2 should provide everything you need and more, and is portable between x86 and x64 native.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thanks for the tip. I'm only using SSE for now, but I didn't now about MMX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differences would/should be pointed out in the documentation. The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6303a3sf(v=vs.90).aspx) is more precise. They explicitly mention this:

> A synonym for **_mm_empty** is **_m_empty**.